# Drools (Maven) Error (Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase)

Tags: java, maven, server, client, drools

I am working on a project, and I am stuck with this Drools part. When I want to interact with the server I get this error msg:

ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule - Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase

Here is my pom file, what could be missing? Thank you very much for your help!

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.irobot</groupId>
  <artifactId>irobot</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>irobot Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>irobot.Client</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mvel/mvel2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.drools8</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena-base</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/knowledge-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
   
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.23</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  
     <properties>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Share complete stack trace here. Probably there are some compilation error with rules.

Comment: I can't past everything it has more than 7000 characters

Comment: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(...